# 4 different scenarios of 'this'. What's the correct interpretation?

Tags: jquery, call, this

These are taken from the tuts-premium Jquery vid tutorials.
http://tutsplus.com/lesson/the-this-keyword/ 
Jeff explains what 'this' is referring to each time but I'm not sure I've grasped the reasoning behind them all.

**E.g. 1**

```
function doSomething(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); 
console.log(this);
} 

$('a').on('click', doSomething);
```

In this case "this refers to the 'a' element" (being in this case the parent object)

I guess that's because here the statement equates to :

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log(this);
    }
```

So 'a' is the parent object

**E.g. 2**

```
var obj = { 
    doIt: function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log(this);
    }
}

$('a').on('click',  obj.doIt);
```

In this case "this still refers to the 'a' element "  (*but apparently it's not the parent object?)

It seems this time we're calling a method but the statement still equates to the same thing as E.g. 1

*One thing in the tutorial has me a bit confused. I thought 'this' always refers to the parent object so in this case 'a' is still the parent object. But (at 05.23 in the tutorial ) he infers that's not the case, stating "there may be times when you want 'this' to refer to it's parent object which would be 'obj' " in which  event he creates e.g.3.

**E.g. 3**

```
var obj = { 
    doIt: function(){ 
    console.log(this);
    }
}

$('a').on('click',  function(e){    
obj.doIt(); 
        };
e.preventDefault();
```

In this case "this refers to the obj object"

I presume this to with the fact that 'this' is in a nested function as this statement equates to :

```
$('a').on('click',  function(){    
function(){ console.log(this);}
};
e.preventDefault();
```

I don't really understand why though, particularly as I read in an article that in nested functions 'this' "loses its way and refers to the head object (window object)".

**E.g.4**

```
var obj = { 
    doIt: function(){ 
    console.log(this);     
    }
}

$('a').on('click',  function(e){    
       obj.doIt.call(this);             
       e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

In this case "This refers to the 'a'"

According to Javascript  Definitive Guide "The first argument to both call() is the object on which the function is to be invoked"
Here "this" is the used as the first argument. But "this" is not the object on which the function is to be invoked??
I think I get  that the call function is there to invoke the function and use its first parameter as a pointer to a different object but I don't get why using 'this' means the function is invoked by 'a'. It's not something I've seen in other call() examples either.

Sorry for such a mammoth post. Hopefully someone's still reading by this stage…

Comment: +1 because it's too late here for me to start responding to this excellent question. No doubt someone else will soon - it's a vital point and one that's generally covered poorly in JS tutorials.

Comment: *"I thought 'this' always refers to the parent object..."* No, don't think of `this` as the parent object. Think of it as a *calling context* whose value can be set in several different ways, one of which happens to be calling a method from an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps clarifying the issue, it can be confusing indeed.

- **When `this` is loose on your code, it will refer to the global object (in web browsers, that is `window`).**

  ```
  console.log(this); // window
  ```
- **When `this` is inside an object method (like on your E.g. 3), it will refer to the object. This aplies to objects instanced with `new`, or as object literals (like on your example).**

  ```
   var obj = { 
       doIt: function(e){ 
           console.log(this);
       }
   }
   obj.doIt(); // obj
  ```
- **Inside an event handler, `this` will refer to the object the event is bound to.**

  ```
  // This is the plain js equivalent of your jQuery example
  document.getElementsByTagName['a'][0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
      console.log(this); // the first anchor on the document
  });

  // This is exactly the same:
  var clickHandler = function(e){
      console.log(this); // the first anchor on the document
  };
  document.getElementsByTagName['a'][0].addEventListener('click', clickHandler); 

  // Even if the handler is defined inside of another object, this will be
  // the obj the event is bound to. It's the case of your E.g. 2
  var obj = { 
      doIt: function(e){  
          console.log(this); // the first anchor on the document
      }
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName['a'][0].addEventListener('click', obj.doIt);
  // When you pass obj.doIt to addEventListener above, you are passing a reference
  // to that function. It's like "stealing" the function from the object
  ```
- **When an object is passed as the first parameter to `Function.call` or `Function.apply`, if `this` appears inside of the function it will refer to the object you passed. It's a way to force what `this` will be pointing to.**

  ```
  var obj = { 
      doIt: function(){ 
          console.log(this); // window 
      }
  }
  obj.doIt.call(window);
  ```

Comment: However, given `obj` with a `doIt` function, if we do `var fn = obj.doIt; fn()`, `this` will refer to `window` inside of `fn`.

Comment: Yes, just like it was on my example with `addEventListener` (except that in that case it will be pointing to a DOM node, not `window`). But the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The way `this` behaves in JavaScript is a little confusing at first. Basically, unlike variables (which are statically scoped), `this` is *dynamically* scoped. That is, the value of `this` is determined by where you *call* the function rather than where you wrote it.

When you pass your function to `on`, it later gets called from a context where `this` is the element in question. This happens *regardless* of how you got that function. That is to say, a function does not care whether you access it using syntax like `obj.fn` or just its name `fn`--the value of the expression is the same in either case.

With things other than functions, this makes sense. Given:

```
var a   = 10,
    obj = { a : 10 };
```

you'll agree that the expressions `a` and `obj.a` have the same value. This is also true of functions.

In short: the value of `this` depends on where and how you call the function rather than how and where you declared it or how you referred to it before calling it.

Comment: We shouldn't confuse `this` with "scope". They're entirely separate. And `this` isn't determined by *where*, but rather by *how* the function is called.

Comment: Taking a closer look, there are several things wrong. Like... *"...it later gets called from a context where this is the element in question"*. This makes no difference. There's no transfer of the enclosing context to the invoked one unless you manually transfer it using `.call()` or `.apply()`. And this... *"...a function does not care whether you access it using syntax like `obj.fn` or just its name `fn`"* ...isn't right either. It very much makes a difference.

Comment: My point was that the expression `f` and `obj.f` have the same value (as long as `f` and `obj.f` point to the same function). Perhaps I was not sufficiently clear on that. As for the other point, you can change the value of `this` without `call` or `apply` by putting the function in the object. So whether you *call* it from an object or by itself matters, but for just accessing it (getting the function as a value) it does not matter.

Comment: Right, but that would mean it depends on *how* you refer to it, which contradicts your last sentence stating *"`this` depends on where you call the function rather than ... how you refer to it."* And yes, you can change `this`,  without `.call()` or `.apply()`, but as I stated, you can't *transfer* the enclosing context to the invoked function without them unless `this` happens to be the same object.

Comment: Hmm, that last sentence does seem wrong. What I meant was that `this` depends on how and where you call the function but not how you referred to it earlier or how and where you declared it. I'll have to update it.

Comment: Well, I guess it's a little better, but *where* plays no role. The invoked function is completely oblivious to its enclosing calling context.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this is a short introduction into the `this` keyword. And have a look into the reference for [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

As jQuery calls (yes, with the `.call()` method) event handlers in the context of the dom element, all your examples are explained.

Answer (score 0):

Really appreciate these responses guys. I posted in the early hrs and have tried (& needed)to take a bit of time to digest your feedback.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this  was a great shout. I've read quite few articles/tuts and this one seems like one of the better ones.

I think the main enlightenment has been that the object bound to 'this' is determined by how/where the function was called (calling context) rather than how or where the function was defined.

**So just to return things to the Q&A scope and attempt to answer my own Q in light of what you guys have responded…**

**E.g. 1** 
Here: the 'doSomething' function was called in context of the click handler so the object bound to 'this' is "a"

**E.g. 2** 
Again the click handler is still triggering the function so the object bound to 'this' is "a"

**E.g. 3** 
In the nested function the calling context is obj.doIt(). So, as he says in tutorial, the object bound to 'this' is "obj".

Although, based on similar logic from developer.mozilla.org example below, isn't the object really bound to "obj.doIt":

```
o.b = {g: independent, prop: 42};  
console.log(o.b.g()); // logs 42
```

"the this binding is only affected by the most immediate member reference…. this inside the function will refer to o.b. The fact that the object is itself a member of o has no consequence; the most immediate reference is all that matters."

**E.g. 4**

Here - 'call''s job is to indirectly invoke the function  as if it's a method of a new object - in this case one we've defined as 'this'. Here 'this' refers to "a'  as it's part of the function triggered by the click handler.

I hope this is a bit closer. I feel like a dunce on this (dire pun intended) because the answers are being presented to me yet I'm still not entirely confident I'm nailing the concept.

If I do have to crawl back to my hole for a while to digest I plead newby status, crash coursing Javascript&JQuery for just a few weeks now.

Thanks again for the feedback everybody.